# How to use React Browser Router in Material UI Drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use Browser Router in react, to populate the content section of a Material UI Drawer.

The code works to make the menu options links to components that are displayed in the content section of the drawer, however, when the page refreshes, there is an issue, because there is not top level route to the component that is rendered within the content of the drawer. The actual page (that is a top level route) that has the Drawer, should reload on page refresh, but instead, the address in the url that reloads, is trying to use the content component instead.

My code is:

```
   import React, {  useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter, useParams,
    useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import theme from "../../../services/appearance/theme";
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


import Menu1 from "../../menu/First";
import Menu2 from "../../menu/Second";



const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerContainer: {
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    maxWidth: `calc(100vw - ${drawerWidth}px)`
  },
}));

export default function ClippedDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  let { topicId } = useParams();



  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
       test
      </AppBar>
     <BrowserRouter>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <div className={classes.drawerContainer}>
        <List>
            
        <ListItem button key="1" component={Link}  to={`${url}/Menu1`}
        >
            <ListItemText primary="First Menu"></ListItemText> 
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button key="2" component={Link} to={`${url}/Menu2`}>
            <ListItemText>Second Menu</ListItemText> 
        </ListItem>
        
    </List>
        </div>
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <Toolbar>test</Toolbar> 

        <Switch>
            <Route path={`${path}/:Menu1`}>
            <Menu1 />
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/:Menu2`}>
            <Menu2 />
            </Route>
        </Switch>    
        
        
        
      </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>  
    </div>
  );
}
```

Does anyone know how to confine the browser router in this particular page, so it only populates the content section of the Drawer - not the actual page url?

The menu page is located at "index.jsx". It is a top level route (equivalent to home/topics in the nesting [documentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nesting-qzy12?from-embed=&file=/example.js:92-118)).

Within that page, is a Material UI Drawer, that has a menu with a link to a component that renders in the content in that index page.

When I load the page for the first time, I get localhost:3000/index. I click on the Menu1 menu item on that page and the url address changes to: localhost3000/Home/Menu1 (and displays the content window of the Material UI Drawer with the component for Menu1 - all correctly). I can refresh that page and the url address remains correct.

However, when I click Menu2 in the Menubar, the url address changes to Home/Menu2, but the content window remains populated with the Menu1 component. It should display Menu2.

How can I adapt the nesting routes example in the documentation to use with the Material UI Drawer?

Comment: did you see documentation in regards of nesting router ? [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Browser Router in App.js. So, it will not give you a blank page. Like this:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
 <MarerialUIDrawer/>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' render=
        {props => <Home {...props} /> }/>
    <Route exact path='/about' render=
        {props => <About {...props} /> }/>
    <Route exact path='/contact' render=
        {props => <Contact {...props} /> }/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

export default App;

Comment: Hi -no, you've misunderstood. I do use Browser Router in App.js (that covers the main pages in the app). However, in order to switch the content of the Material UI drawer (corresponding to the item in the drawer menu), there is a different question. Thank you anyway for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it.

I didn't need the colon in the Route path.

This:
<Route path={`${path}/:Menu1`}>

Should be:

<Route path={`${path}/Menu1`}>